# bxSlider as module loads the body of my template again

Tags: joomla-2.5, module

I face a problem with plugin bxSlider and my 2.5 Joomla website. I am using it as a custom module. The problem is that when it loads, under my image it loads the whole template again! This happens only if I load an image. If I remove it, the problem dissappeared.

The plugin I use is this: http://bxslider.com/

I think that the problem is here(lin 271 of code in jquery.bxslider.js):

```
var loadElements = function(selector, callback){
            var total = selector.find('img, iframe').length;
            if (total == 0){
                callback();
                return;
            }
            var count = 0;
            selector.find('img, iframe').each(function(){
                $(this).one('load', function() {
                  if(++count == total) callback();
                }).each(function() {
                  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
                });
            });
        }
```

Do you have any ideas how this one can be fixed?

Comment: i think it will be better if you post a link to a page of your website where this happens.

Answer (score 2):

bxSlider latest versions conflict with mootools
Here is the issue I posted some time ago.
https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/1004

So either use an older bxSlider code, or don't use bxSlider.

Joomla 3 still may use mootools. And Joomla 2.5 uses it anyway as far as I remember.